Find partial match within an element
I have a dynamic elements and I need to fetch all adults first name and last name into an array of objects using jquery
like
[
  [
    {
      "first_name": "Anish",
      "last_name": "gopi"
    }, {
      "first_name": "Vinay",
      "last_name": "prasad"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "first_name": "Ananaya",
      "last_name": "vital"
    }, {
     "first_name": "Guru",
     "last_name": "govind"
    }
  ]
]



let i = 0;
$('.pax_details').each(function(index, item) {
  $(item).find('.adult_pax').each(function(index, adult) {
    console.log($(adult).find('input[name^="first_name_"]').val());
  });
  i++;
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_1" value="Anish" />
    <input name="last_name_1" value="gopi" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_2" value="Vinay" />
    <input name="last_name_2" value="prasad" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_3" value="Ananaya" />
    <input name="last_name_3" value="vital" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_4" value="Guru" />
    <input name="last_name_4" value="govind" />
  </div>
</div>




How does your attempt not meet your expectations?

I don't see how input[name^="salute_"] is relevant. Also, don't debug using alert. Try console.log instead. And when do you run your jQuery? Your example HTML has no form values by default.

I'd give the inputs a class (class="first_name", class="last_name") and use those to populate your array.

Why doesn't your code create an array like you want?

This solution does what you want: It first scans for the .pax_details elements, then subsequently looks for all <input> elements within them and reduces each "pair" of inputs into a single Object with a first_name and last_name field in it.

Note that I added values to the HTML inputs for demonstration purposes

EDIT
In contrast to the other solutions, this one avoids the unneeded DOM traversal for the .adult_pax elements and instead uses the index argument of the function passed to .reduce to create new Objects or manipulate existing ones. It's possible to ignore the intermediate query because jQuery (as well as .querySelectorAll) return the elements in the order they appear in the DOM and we therefor know that each firstname is on an even input and that the odd ones stand for the lastname.


const results = $('.pax_details')                            // <-- get the detail elements
  .toArray()
  .map(detailElement => {                                    // <-- for each details element, project ...
    return $('input', detailElement)                         // <-- ... the contained <input>s ...
      .toArray()                                             
      .reduce(                                               // <-- ... into an array of objects
        (list, input, index) => {
          if (index % 2 === 0) {                             // <-- for the even inputs 0, 2, 4, and so on ...
            return list.concat({ first_name: input.value }); // <-- ... add a new item to the list and return the (new) list.
          }
          const item = list[list.length - 1];                // <-- for odd inputs take a pointer to the last entry ...
          item.last_name = input.value;                      // <-- ... assign a last_name property to the entry ...
          return list;                                       // <-- ... and return the list
        },
        []
      );
  });
  
console.log(results);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pax_details">
    <div class="adult_pax">
      <input name="first_name_1" value="A1">
      <input name="last_name_1" value="A2">
    </div>
    <div class="adult_pax">
      <input name="first_name_2" value="B1">
      <input name="last_name_2" value="B2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pax_details">
    <div class="adult_pax">
      <input name="first_name_3" value="C1">
      <input name="last_name_3" value="C2">
    </div>
    <div class="adult_pax">
      <input name="first_name_4" value="D1">
      <input name="last_name_4" value="D2">
    </div>
  </div>




To get what you ask (nested array), you indeed need to loop the pax_details
jQuery


let adults = $('.pax_details').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('.adult_pax').map(function() {
    return [
      $(this)
      .find('input')
      .get()
      .reduce((obj, input) => (obj[input.name.replace(/_\d{1,}$/, '')] = input.value, obj), {})
    ];
  }).get()];
}).get();

console.log(adults);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_1" value="Anish" />
    <input name="last_name_1" value="gopi" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_2" value="Vinay" />
    <input name="last_name_2" value="prasad" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_3" value="Ananaya" />
    <input name="last_name_3" value="vital" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_4" value="Guru" />
    <input name="last_name_4" value="govind" />
  </div>
</div>



Plain JS


let adults =      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pax_details'))
  .map(details => Array.from(details.querySelectorAll('.adult_pax'))
    .map(pax =>   Array.from(pax.querySelectorAll('input'))
      .reduce((obj, input) => (obj[input.name.replace(/_\d{1,}$/, '')] = input.value, obj), {})
    )
  );
console.log(adults);
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_1" value="Anish" />
    <input name="last_name_1" value="gopi" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_2" value="Vinay" />
    <input name="last_name_2" value="prasad" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_3" value="Ananaya" />
    <input name="last_name_3" value="vital" />
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_4" value="Guru" />
    <input name="last_name_4" value="govind" />
  </div>
</div>




I want to note that OP said this: I need to fetch all adults first name and last name into an array of objects using jquery. So even though this works, there isn't any jQuery involved and you could argue this is an answer in a wrong programming language..

@Wimanicesir Please look again. I do not really like jQuery anymore

@Wimanicesir Since when is jQuery a language?

The jQuery-way to do this would be to map all the details to an array of adults, where each adult is a reduction of the fields.
You can grab the input field's name and use a regular expression to match on everything before the trailing underscore + number.
The trick here is to wrap the returned values in an square brackets. If you do not, you will get a flat list at the end.


const details = $('.pax_details').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('.adult_pax').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('input').toArray().reduce((acc, input) => {
      const $input = $(input);
      const [, name] = $input.attr('name').match(/^(\w+)_\d+$/);
      if (name) {
        acc[name] = $input.val().trim();
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})];
  }).toArray()];
}).toArray();

console.log(details);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_1" value="Anish">
    <input name="last_name_1" value="gopi">
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_2" value="Vinay">
    <input name="last_name_2" value="prasad">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pax_details">
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_3" value="Ananaya">
    <input name="last_name_3" value="vital">
  </div>
  <div class="adult_pax">
    <input name="first_name_4" value="Guru">
    <input name="last_name_4" value="govind">
  </div>
</div>




Is that not almost exactly what I do (except you use a .toArray where I use .get) and a different regex
